# Data is getting saved and deleted even after 404 error in spring-boot and H2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, h2

I am new to H2 and Spring-boot combination, I am using all the latest updates to create a simple rest-API, I have created multiple endpoints to manipulate and present data in my controller class but mystifyingly whenever I am posting a new object I am getting 404 error in postman but I am still able to see the data inserted into h2 DB same goes for deletion I get 404 but it still deletes the data from the table, I am pretty sure I am making a very silly mistake, I have tried to debug it but couldn't find any substantial error to follow. below are my classes -

Controller -

```
package com.nerdbot.student.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.nerdbot.student.entity.Student;
import com.nerdbot.student.entity.repo.StudentRepo;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class StudentController {


    @Autowired
    StudentRepo repo;
      @RequestMapping(value="student",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody Student getValueByid(@RequestParam(value="id", required=true) String id) {
          Student s = repo.findOne(Long.valueOf(id).longValue());
          return s;
        }

      @RequestMapping(value="allstudent",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody List<Student> getAllValue() {
          List<Student>s = repo.findAll();
          return s;
        }

      @RequestMapping(value="delete",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody String getdeleteById(@RequestParam(value="id", required=true) String id) {
          repo.delete(Long.valueOf(id).longValue());
          return id + "- deleted ";
        }

      @RequestMapping(value="add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String add( @RequestBody Student input) {

          try {
            repo.save(input);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getStackTrace());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

          return "Saved";

        }


      @RequestMapping(value="deleteAll",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String getdeleteById() {
          repo.deleteAll();;
          return "All record deleted";
        }




}
```

Domain class -

```
package com.nerdbot.student.entity;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;



    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


}
```

Jpa repository -

```
package com.nerdbot.student.entity.repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.nerdbot.student.entity.Student;

public interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

}
```

h2 DB Spring properties -

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/spring-boot-h2-db
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Please if you could guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I am tending to find the issue as soon as I post it here :D, this is how my issue got resolved -
I returned a `ResponseEntity` object instead of a `String`

```
 @RequestMapping(value="add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public  ResponseEntity<Void> add( @RequestBody Student input) {

          try {
            repo.save(input);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getStackTrace());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

          return ResponseEntity.ok().build();

        }
```

Same goes for delete all request.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following method that create a new product:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/products")
public Product create(@RequestBody Product product) {

    return repo.save(product);
}
```

I was getting a 404 error in the Postman, because, of the use of `@Controller` at the class lever annotation. After I changed to the `@RestController`, the error goes away and all looks fine.